# I can't import a CSV into Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014 due to Pre Execute error 0xc020802e

Tags: mysql, sql-server, csv

I'm trying import a CSV file into SQL Server Management Studio 2014 but keep hitting errors every time I try. Specifically, I get a Pre-execute error:

> ### Messages Error 0xc020802e: Data Flow Task 1: The data type for "Source
>
> download_fresh_filename_com_06_Apr_17_4EB41F5D720E569B7AD1D854B1EC3142_csv.Outputs[Flat
>   File Source Output].Columns[Target URL]" is DT_NTEXT, which is not
>   supported with ANSI files. Use DT_TEXT instead and convert the data to
>   DT_NTEXT using the data conversion component.  (SQL Server Import and
>   Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0202094: Data Flow Task 1: Unable to
>   retrieve column information from the flat file connection manager. 
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc004701a: Data Flow
>   Task 1: Source -
>   download_fresh_filename_com_06_Apr_17_4EB41F5D720E569B7AD1D854B1EC3142_csv
>   failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202094.  (SQL
>   Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Information 0x4004300b: Data Flow
>   Task 1: "Destination -
>   download_fresh_filename_com_06_Apr_17_4EB41F5D720E569B7AD1D854B1EC3142"
>   wrote 0 rows.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

The CSV is UTF8 encoded, ~114,900 rows 20 columns. Here's what I've tried so far with no success:

- Under Choose a Data Source>advanced I've set the data type to [DT_TEXT] which didn't work,
- tried [DT_NTEXT] but still didn't work.
- Under Review Data Type Mapping I've set On Error (global) to Ignore, still didn't work

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed a box I was missing before in the Import Wizard: under choose a data source>flat file source there is a "text qualifier" definition which is set to  by default, I changed it to ".

Also in the same section under Advanced, I changed the column width from the default 50 to 1000 for all rows.

Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a limited number of rows to narrow down the row having the rogue values. 
Also, funny though it may sound, in such cases, I have had better success by importing it first into Excel, and then onward to SQL Server. In other cases, to Excel, onward to Access and further on to SQL Server. Strange world.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried importing just the first few rows of data and I got the same error. I also tried to import the data as an xlsx file but it didn't work. I got the error: 

The operation could not be completed.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)

Comment: By "importing data as an xlsx file", did you mean : (a) Import from Excel to SQLS OR(b) Import CSV to Excel ?

Whether the CSV is malformed, what is the source of CSV , whether other CSV files from same source worked in the past,  try importing those sample files again into a test SQLS database to test. 

Does CSV have double or single quotes as part of data ? Like, "Taj Mahal" or Genelia D'Souza ? Whether comma is part of content, whether properly enclosed in quotes ?

Re-generate CSV from source using some other char as separator, ex: : | or ~ , and check.

Answer (score 0):

Error clearsly indicates regarding ANSI file, Solution is to use Unicode. There is tick as shown below. When you check this box, it will work fine.

[image]